# Calculate in Function

Tags: vba, function, types

underlying is a part of a bigger code I am writing. I simplified the problem in this example Function. The 'Formuletekst' can change i.e. "*" or "/' or something else. How can I write the Function in order to have the calculated value (10) for test instead of the output "500/50" which it gives in this example function? Many thanks!

Amir

```
'IN this case Formuletekst = "/"
Function TT(FormuleTekst)
teg = Formuletekst
TT = 500 & teg & 50
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather suggest to use the `Application.Evaluate` method, to make sure to catch every string that might be an expression:

```
tt = "500/50"
aa = Application.Evaluate(tt)
```

aa will be equal to 10, and this will happen for every kind of Excel operation you might pass into the function.

The [evaluate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019(v=office.15).aspx) method is the best way to manage this kind of input that are "strings" but at the same time "human readable operations".

Other example to show you a more complex input that wouldn't be managed by the other alternative you've been proposed:

```
tt = "500/50 + 10/20 - 4"
aa = Application.Evaluate(tt)
```

This input will return `aa = 6.5`, but I believe parsing the string and performing the operation would be much longer to implement (and not safer anyway, if the built-in exists already).

So, my suggestion is just to write

```
TT = Application.Evaluate("500" & teg & "50")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put an IF condition:

```
Function TT(FormuleTekst)
teg = Formuletekst
IF teg = "/" Then
TT = 500/50
Else
TT = 500*5
End Function
```

For MS-Excel, you can use an empty cell (e.g A15) to put the formula and can return the same to TT. Something like this:

```
Function TT(FormuleTekst)
teg = FormuleTekst
TT = "=" & 500 & teg & 50
ActiveSheet.Range("A15").Value = TT
TT = ActiveSheet.Range("A15").Value
End Function
```

Comment: Yes but there are more possibilties then "*" and "/". I simplified the problem in the question.

Comment: Are you using this in MS-Excel?

Comment: Yes in Excel. It's a Function within a bigger code. Where the TT calculation is not fixed.